# Psycopg2 - Passing variable in the where clause

Tags: python, amazon-redshift, psycopg2

I am trying to run a SQL script in Python where I am passing a variable in the where clause as below:

```
cursor.execute(f"""select * from table where type = variable_value""")
```

In the above query, `variable_value` has the value that I am trying to use in the where clause. I am however getting an error `psycopg2.errors.UndefinedColumn: column "variable_value" does not exist in table`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per psycopg2 documentation the [execute](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.execute) function takes variables as an extra parameter.

```
cursor.execute("""select * from table where type = %(value)s """, {"value": variable_value})
```

More examples in [psycopg2 user manual.](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries).

Also please read carefully the section about [SQL injection](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#the-problem-with-the-query-parameters) - the gist is, you should not quote parameters in your query, the `execute` function will take care of that to prevent the injection of harmful SQL.

---

Also to explain the error you are getting - the query you're sending is comparing two identifiers (`type` and `variable_value`). The `table` does not contain `variable_value` column, hence the error.

I believe, you intended to use [*string interpolation*](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation) to construct the query, but you forgot the `{}`. It would work like this:

```
cursor.execute(f"""select * from table where type = '{variable_value}'""")
```

⚠️ but **because of** previously mentioned **SQL injection, it is not a recommended way!**.